# Using cakephp to grab a try/catch from a stored procedure

Tags: php, html, css

Hi so i have a model loader from bootstrap and all i needed was a div tag.

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

when the page loads the spinning wheel pops up. my question is i only wish this loader to appear during the loading process on the web page. so when i click submit it takes about 4 seconds well during those 4 seconds i wish for this spinning wheel to pop up and disappear after the page loads. i am a little baffled on how to do this in php with just a div tag. any pointers would be awesome.

Answer (score -1):

Found this in w3schools. It might help you :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5

CSS key part:

```
#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML :

```
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>
```

Script :

```
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

This should delay the page long enough to make use of the loading animation

Hope it helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21662342)

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks very much! That's exactly what we need.